# Was Slenderman the basis for the movie's Hollowgast design?

Tags: character, production, miss-peregrines-home-for-peculiar

In Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children, the secondary villains are Hollowgasts, large, monstrous, faceless creatures.  Their design is exactly like the creepy pasta urban legend of Slenderman. Long limbs, no facial features, hides in the shadows, hunts children, very sharp suit. Even the tentacles are similar, though the book used tentacles from their mouths, and Slenderman has tentacles from his limbs/back.

Was this intentionally done? Is there any production or word of God explication for the similarity? The book examples of Hollowgasts have facial features, and are somewhat different.

Comment: In *Miss Peregrine's Home For Peculiar Children,* there are monsters called Hollowgasts. These monsters and known to have killed "Victor" who is a peculiar. Who do these Hollowgasts look like you ask? Slender man of course! This was the design of Slenderman. But why? These Hollowgasts hunt children like Slender. Have suits like Slender. And are faceless like Slender. They are also both monsters. The only difference is the Hollowgasts have tentacles for mouthes not back limbs. Why was this done? And what does this movie have to do with it? Is there something the viewers don't know about? Why we

Comment: Actually, I can't remember what book but I read on old book in like 2008 about old monsters, there was a drawing similar.

Answer (score 1):

There are no **official** answers by producers if the hollowgasts are based on slenderman or not, but everything indicates that they indeed **are**.

> While in the book they resemble humans with tentacles protruding from their mouths, in the film adaptation their design was clearly far more based on Slender Man, as they are portrayed as bald, pale, unrealistically tall, wearing suits, and are missing most of their face.
>
> Even without the visual similarities, both possess tentacles, are very tall in stature, and prey on children. In the books, they fed on the children's souls, while in the films they consume their eyes. Also like Slenderman, most people are unable to see them.
>
> The main difference is that the Hollowgasts origin are known, and they can be controlled by others, rather than being the ones in control like Slender Man.

For me it seems like they look like a mixture between the hollowgast book version and the slenderman.

Source: [Slenderman Connection Wiki](http://slendermanconnection.wikia.com/wiki/Hollowgasts)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly to use a up to date MONSTER like slender man to scare children and adults alike. Its a movie trick I think.

Comment: A good theory, but do you have any source to back this up?

Comment: As cde said, do you have anything to back this up and make it more than just your personal theory? But also, I would also love to hear you flesh this out some more. e.g. Why would the movie aim to scare adults and children alike, rather than just being aimed at one age group? And if the goal is to scare all ages, why are similarities to Slenderman the right way to do so? What do you mean by "up-to-date" and why is it important that the monster be "up-to-date"? (Are other things incapable of scaring people?) Etc, etc. There should be an "edit" button below your post that you can use to edit it.